# Удалить строку с одним вхождением, но оставить с двумя (sed, awk, grep...)

Tags: linux, sed, grep, awk

Допустим требуется удалить строку, имеющую менее или только одну цифру, но оставить с двумя цифрами и более, например из

```
ABCDE
FDH5U
77TYR
R4E66
```

получить

```
77TYR
R4E66
```

Как? Можно например с помощью `sed -n '/[[:digit:]]/p'` отсеять только те, которые имеют любое кол-во цифр, можно к примеру тут задать минимальное кол-во вхождений?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужны строки с 2 и более цифрами подряд:

```
sed -rn '/[[:digit:]]{2,}/p'
```

Если нужны строки с 2 и более цифрами в строке:

```
sed -rn '/([[:digit:]].*){2,}/p'
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, только первое наверное тоже с -r : sed -rn '/[[:digit:]]{2,}/p'

Answer (score 0):

Например:

```
sed '/^[^0-9]*[0-9]\?[^0-9]*$/d'
```

Удаляем строки если они соответствуют выражению "Начало строки, НЕ цифра (0 и более), возможно одна цифра, НЕ цифра (0 и более), Конец строки".